# Running tests in a Seam project which was not generated by seam-gen

Tags: java, seam, integration-testing, testng

I've got a project firstly written using EJB 2, then migrated to Spring and after all migrated to JBoss Seam 2.2.0 (which is the situation I'm dealing with). It will run over Tomcat but for now it is executed over JBoss 4.2 (although I believe this fact is irrelevant). My task is to run all tests written before the last migration.

After a lot of googling, I wrote something like this:

```
public class CustomUserDAOTest extends SeamTest {
    @Test
    public void f() throws Exception {
        new ComponentTest() {
            @Override
            protected void testComponents() throws Exception {
                CustomUserDAO customUserDAO = (CustomUserDAO) Component.getInstance(CustomUserDAOBean.class);
                List<CustomUser> users = customUserDAO.getAll();
                assertNotNull(users);
            }
        }.run();
    }
}
```

That is good because I managed to get instances of CustomUserDAOBean and its dependencies, but when I run the test I get another problem:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: exception invoking: getTransaction
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invokeAndWrap(Reflections.java:154)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.callComponentMethod(Component.java:2249)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.unwrap(Component.java:2275)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:2041)
    [OMITTED]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103)
    at br.com.visent.sicorp.server.dao.impl.CustomUserDAOBean_$$_javassist_seam_1.listAll(CustomUserDAOBean_$$_javassist_seam_1.java)
    at br.com.visent.sicorp.server.dao.test.CustomUserDAOTest$1.testComponents(CustomUserDAOTest.java:24)
    at org.jboss.seam.mock.AbstractSeamTest$ComponentTest.run(AbstractSeamTest.java:162)
    [OMITTED]
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:856)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:110)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:205)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:174)
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:645)
    [OMITTED]
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invokeAndWrap(Reflections.java:144)
    ... 45 more
```

I found some comments about it on the Web but no solution. What should I do? Has someone any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just create a seam-gen project, and diff against your project to see if there are any settings or something else you have done wrong?

Comment: Shervin, your suggestion was excellent! I answer my own question below. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've followed the suggestion of Shervin above and got a solution. Actually, when we create a project using seam-gen the `src/test` directory will contain a `readme.txt` with the following content:

```
If you want to run tests using the Eclipse TestNG plugin, you'll need to add
these jars to the top of your TestNG classpath. Using the Run Dialog, select the
XML suite to run, and select these entries from the project tree:

/lib/test/jboss-embedded-all.jar
/lib/test/hibernate-all.jar
/lib/test/thirdparty-all.jar
/lib/jboss-embedded-api.jar
/lib/jboss-deployers-client-spi.jar
/lib/jboss-deployers-core-spi.jar

You also need to add the Embedded JBoss bootstrap folder, which you can do by
clicking on the Advanced... button.

/bootstrap

Seam uses JBoss Embedded in its unit and integration testing. This has an
additional requirement when using JDK 6. Add the following VM argument to the VM
args tab in the TestNG launch configuration for your suite.

-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true 

Please be sure to use JDK 6 Update 4 or better (>= 1.6.0_04) if you are using
JDK 6. The Update 4 release upgraded to JAXB 2.1 which removes a problem with
earlier versions of Sun's JDK 6 which required overriding the JAXB libraries
using the endorsed directory. 

To add tests to your project create a TestNG xml descriptor called *Test.xml
(e.g. FooTest.xml) next to your test classes and run ant test.
```

I opened the "Run Configurations" of the test (which can be made through the button "Run" on the toolbar, clicking in the little black down arrow and selecting "Run Configurations"), added the jars listed above in the "Classpath" tab (except for `jboss-deployers-client-spi.jar`, which was problematic) and added `-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true` to the "VM Arguments" in the "Arguments" tab because I am using Java 6.

I still have some problems but this specific one is solved.